# Omitting punctuation at end of quote

Tags: punctuation

I am using a block quote in my essay. The quote I chose ends with an em dash. When I am incorporating this quote into my essay, can I omit the em dash?  Is 1) or 2) correct? It is MLA format.

So 1)

> ...Blah blah blah - (Author's last name, page number)

2. 

> ...Blah blah blah. (Author's last name, page number)

Would I have to indicate that I changed it from an em dash to a period using brackets?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question objectively, since punctuation is primarily a matter of *style*; it's for this reason that questions about punctuation on our site are nearly always closed as being "primarily opinion-based". Alternatively, if your question is about interpreting how a certain style guide should be used in a particular situation, then that too is off-topic here. For further guidance, see [ask], and I can recommend our brief EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the style guide you're using.

The [Purdue OWL website](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_quotations.html) gives an example where a block quote is ended with four dots (comprised of an ellipsis and a period) because the material quoted does not end with a period.

On the other hand, [this blog](https://killzoneblog.com/2020/06/when-where-why-and-how-to-use-block-quotes-and-ellipses.html#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20Chicago%20Manual,pressing%20CTRL%20%2B%20ALT%20%2B%20Period.) says:

> According to the Chicago Manual of Style, never use ellipses at the beginning or end of a block quote,

which I think leaves you with no choice but to end a block quote with a period if you follow their rules.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recomended way to write such information.

*From [Citation Guide (MLA 8th Edition): In-Text Citation](https://otis.libguides.com/mla_citations/in-text)*

> Example of a Long Quotation
>
> At the end of Lord of the Flies the boys are struck with the realization of their behaviour:
>
> The tears began to flow and sobs shook him. He gave himself up to them now for the              first time on the island; great, shuddering spasms of grief that seemed to wrench his
>              whole body.  His voice rose under the black smoke before the burning wreckage of
>              the island; and
> infected by that emotion, the other little boys began to shake and
>              sob too. (Golding 186)

> There are 4 rules that apply to long quotations that are different from regular quotations:
>
> 1. The line before your long quotation, when you're introducing the quote, usually ends with a colon.
> 2. The long quotation is indented half an inch from the rest of the text, so it looks like a block of text.
> 3. There are no quotation marks around the quotation.
> 4. The period at the end of the quotation comes before your in-text citation as opposed to after, as it does with regular quotations.

From the fourth rule you see that the full stop  (BrE, AmE and also BrE: period) that end the quoting sentence is not placed as usual, but at the end of the quote; this means that if you have in mind to include a full stop that is at the end of the quote, you won't be able to make clear to the reader that there is this inclusion as that would entail the writing of two consecutive full stops; this is not done, the usual practice being to conflate such punctuation into a single one.
However, if you thought that in the source you are quoting there should have been a full stop at the end of the quote, but that for some reason it was missing, and that you want to add this punctuation mark, this can be done as usual (I think), as you suggest ([.]) and as the following reference specifies (they mention only the addition of words, but I believe there is nothing special about punctuation).

*From **Punctuation, Quotes inside Quotes, and Altering Quotes (PDF)***

> You may not significantly change a quotation, but you may add clarifying
> information to a quote using brackets ([ ]). Bracketed words can replace a confusing term in the sentence (option 1) or add extra words for clarification (option 2).
> For example:
>
> 1. Original quote: “Bob asked Jorge about his family’s history.”
>    Option 1: “Bob asked [his grandfather] about his family’s history.”
>    Option 2: “Bob asked Jorge [his grandfather] about his family’s history.”

Thus, if you want to add some punctuation the result is as follows.

- ...Blah blah blah[<*punctuation*>]. (Author's last name, page number)
- ...Blah blah blah[.]. (Author's last name, page number) (*in the case of a full stop*)

Comment: I checked the site, but my original quote does not end with a period. Just double checking, I still put a period?

Comment: @Willis I added some information to my answer.